# How can I, or can I, override a virtual method without a base class but with a pointer?

Tags: c++

Can I access `stuff()` with a pointer?

I am trying to make my script component work with `entity` in my entity component system.

Here is a simplified version of my problem:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

class Entity
{
    virtual void stuff(){}
};

class Component
{
public:
    Entity* entity;
};

class Script : public Component
{
    // can i override entity virtual void stuff() from here? something like
    //void entity::stuff() override
};

int main()
{
    Entity* entity = new Entity();
    Component* component = new Component();
    component->entity = entity;
}
```

Comment: No. `Script` is not an `Entity`, so it cannot override `Entity::stuff()` (but nor would it make sense to). What is the specific problem you are hoping to solve? It's possible there may be a workaround, but without more specific details about what you are trying to actually accomplish, it's hard to suggest an alternative.

Comment: If you want to override `stuff`, you need to inherit from `Entity`.

Comment: I think this is a classic case of a so-called "XY problem". Search for that term online, if you don't know it. As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: To do what you are asking for would require manually altering `entity`'s vtable at runtime to redirect its methods to your own.  Not something that the C++ standard supports, but is technically doable, if you know how your compiler lays out the vtable in memory.

Comment: @RemyLebeau You probably lost him at vtable. But you're right, simply put each class comes with its own list of virtual functions. Derived classes sort of make a copy of that list and can override functions in that list with their own (they must match signatures).  And that list is called the vtable. And you can't override vtables from other classes except by inheritance (unless you do really hacky stuff and probably wreck a lot in the process)

Comment: I'm not sure what the purpose is but you could have a `virtual` proxy in `Component` `virtual void stuff() { entity->stuff(); }` [example](https://godbolt.org/z/ss1qrM9vK). There's no actual connection between the `stuff` functions in `Entity` and `Component` (other than the name) but ... perhaps good enough.

Answer (score 2):

No. C++ does not let you override anything outside the inheritance hierarchy where the virtual member exists.

However, you can produce the desired effect by making a new class based on `Entity`, and overriding the virtual function there:

```
class EntityWithOverride : public Entity {
public:
   EntityWithOverride(Entity* actualEntity) : actualEntity_(actualEntity) {}
   void stuff() override {
      // your override goes here
   }
   // unchanged stuff calls the corresponding functions of actualEntity_
   void unchangedStuff1() {
      actualEntity_->unchangedStuff1();
   }
   void unchangedStuff2() {
      actualEntity_->unchangedStuff2();
   }
private:
   Entity* actualEntity_;
};
```

Now the script can do this:

```
EntityWithOverride withOverride(entity);
withOverride.stuff(); // your new code runs
withOverride.unchangedStuff1(); // original code runs
```